# How can I display just 'n' tick datetime labels in a plot or make octave chose a good number of ticks for me?

Tags: octave

I want to display a column of a more than 5800 rows matrix.

The matrix contains in its first columns, the year, the month and the day which corresponds to that row. It spans almost 20 years (but no exact dates, first record begins 30th January 2001)-

```
octave:4> data(1:10,:)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 10:

    198.000000000   2001.000000000      1.000000000     30.000000000      0.917600000      0.928000000      0.914700000      0.926900000      0.000133000      0.000108000
    199.000000000   2001.000000000      1.000000000     31.000000000      0.926800000      0.942600000      0.926600000      0.941300000      0.000160000      0.000133000
    200.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      1.000000000      0.941400000      0.944700000      0.936400000      0.937300000      0.000083000      0.000160000
    201.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      2.000000000      0.937400000      0.942100000      0.931800000      0.936400000      0.000103000      0.000083000
    202.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      4.000000000      0.936600000      0.939700000      0.936600000      0.939400000      0.000033000      0.000103000
    203.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      5.000000000      0.939300000      0.943900000      0.936500000      0.937100000      0.000074000      0.000033000
    204.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      6.000000000      0.937200000      0.938900000      0.928200000      0.929600000      0.000107000      0.000074000
    205.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      7.000000000      0.929500000      0.935200000      0.926100000      0.928800000      0.000091000      0.000107000
    206.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      8.000000000      0.928900000      0.929200000      0.915300000      0.918700000      0.000139000      0.000091000
    207.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      9.000000000      0.918800000      0.927800000      0.913500000      0.924000000      0.000143000      0.000139000

 Columns 11 through 14:

      0.013034000      0.010134000     -0.003166000      0.009034000
      0.015680000      0.015480000     -0.000520000      0.014180000
      0.008134000      0.003134000     -0.005166000     -0.004266000
      0.010094000      0.004494000     -0.005806000     -0.001206000
      0.003034000      0.003034000     -0.000066000      0.002734000
      0.007252000      0.004452000     -0.002948000     -0.002348000
      0.010486000      0.001486000     -0.009214000     -0.007814000
      0.008918000      0.005518000     -0.003582000     -0.000882000
      0.013622000      0.000022000     -0.013878000     -0.010478000
      0.014014000      0.008714000     -0.005586000      0.004914000
```

I define some variables to help identifying which specific columns I am using:

```
YEAR = 2;
MONTH = 3;
DAY = 4;
CLOSE = 8;
```

Then I want to plot column 8 (CLOSE) and display in the X axis the dates. I do not know which options do I have to display a reasonable number of dates.

This is what I tried:

```
figure(2)
xdates = datenum(data(:,YEAR),data(:,MONTH),data(:,DAY))
plot(xdates,data(:,CLOSE))
ax = gca
set (ax, "xtick", xdates);
datetick ("x", 1000, "keepticks");
```

But this generates:

[image: xticks]

1. How can I have a proper display of x axis ticks, limiting the number of displayed ticks?
2. Is it possible to display just months/years instead of day/month/year?

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a valid option. I include the answer in case it might help others:

```
figure(2)
xdates = datenum(data(:,YEAR),data(:,MONTH),data(:,DAY))
plot(xdates,data(:,CLOSE))
ax = gca
set (ax, "xtick", datenum (2000:1:2020,1,1));
datetick("x", 'yy', "keepticks");
```